# Hudson - SVN Check out multiple url under same location

Tags: svn, hudson

I am using hudson for automatic my build.I am using svn and I want to check out from two different svn url into same location for example

check out from svn://xx.xx.xx.xx/project/trunck/myAPP1 to workspace
check out from svn://xx.xx.xx.xx/project/trunck/myAPP2 to workspace

It throws error in HUDSON+SVN but the same is done by Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make two subfolders(myAPP1,myAPP2) under workspace folder,then checkout svn://xx.xx.xx.xx/project/trunck/myAPP1 to myAPP1 folder, myAPP2 you can do the same operation  as myAPP1.

Comment: My question clearly states that I need to checkout under the under same directory.That is APP1/* to workspace and APP2/* to workspace

Comment: @dineshkumar: You can not do that with subversion! Check the documentation of svn. However, what you can do is to checkout into two locations and then copy the contents of one folder into the other. This heavily impairs your ability to use svn update. Eclipse obviously does some tricks to make you believe that you can checkout two projects into the same directory.

Comment: @PeterSchuetze Finally I checked out the each projects instead checking out from the parent folder